# Como selecionar uma classe em tempo de execução baseando-se num RequestParam usando Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Digamos que eu tenha a seguinte @RestController no meu código que utiliza o Spring MVC:

```
@RestController
public class Exemplo {

@RequestMapping(value = "exemplo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public InterfaceDeExemplo exemplo(@RequestParam String escolha) {
    Interface resultado;
    /* Cria uma instância por aqui. */
    return resultado;
}

}
```

E digamos ainda que eu tenha algumas implementações da minha *InterfaceDeExemplo*, **ImplementacaoA**, **ImplementacaoB** e **ImplementacaoC** disponíveis em tempo de execução e que eu tenha de escolher entre elas a partir do **@RequestParam String escolha**.

Sei que seria possível escolher usando os padrões de projeto de Factory, mas estou procurando por uma forma de fazer isso usando injeção de dependências.

Verifiquei que talvez a solução para este problema estivesse relacionada à anotação @Conditional do Spring, mas não sei como pegaria o valor da **@RequestParam String escolha** na minha classe que implemente a interface *Condition*.

Comment: Oi Gabriel, talvez eu esteja super simplificando o problema, mas não bastaria você injetar o `ApplicationContext`e recuperar a implementação usando alguma variação de `getBean`? E o que você está tentando fazer ao retornar essa `Interface` como resultado?

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly o retorno simplesmente vira um `JSON` e é enviado ao cliente. O parâmetro que ali eu chamei de escolha é na verdade o idioma, pois em cada idioma eu vou usar um algoritmo diferente para realizar a tradução (devido a isso não posso simplesmente traduzir as strings do projeto). Tentei seguir o padrão de projeto `Strategy` pra isso. No caso de eu usar o `ApplicationContext`, eu vou estar simplesmente implementando uma `Factory` nos métodos `getBean`, não? Minha dúvida era se seria possível fazer isso sem implementar a `Factory` implicitamente em algum lugar.

Comment: Pensei em algo mais simples: Digamos que você tenha a interface `Tradutor` com um método `traduzir`. Adicionalmente você tem as implementações `TradutorPtBR`, `TradutorEnUS`, etc como beans do Spring. Você simplesmente usaria o método `getBean` para recuperar o bean correto  (e.g., pelo nome compondo `"tradutor" + lingua`). O `ApplicationContext` é, entre outras coisas, uma bean factory. Mas no caso você não implementa nenhum padrão explicitamente, está apenas usando o que o Spring te dá.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly entendi. Tinha resolvido o problema aqui de uma forma parecida, porém usando *reflection*. Vou tentar usar a sua abordagem que me parece menos propícia a erro.